# Achieving interactive large-dataset map-reduce on AWS/GCE in the least lines of code / script

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, mapreduce, google-compute-engine

I have 1 billion rows of data (about 400GB uncompressed; about 40GB compressed) that I would like to process in map-reduce style, and I have two executables (binaries, not scripts) that can handle the "map" and "reduce" steps. The "map" step can process about 10,000 rows per second, per core, and its output is approximately 1MB in size, regardless of the size of its input. The "reduce" step can process about 50MB / second (excluding IO latency).

Assume that I can pre-process the data once, to do whatever I'd like such as compress it, break it into pieces, etc. For simplicity, assume input is plain text and each row terminates with a newline and each newline is a row terminator.

Once that one-time pre-processing is complete, the goal is to be able to execute a request within 30 seconds. So, if my only bottleneck is the map job (which I don't know will really be true-- it could very well be the IO), and assuming I can do all the reduce jobs in under 5 seconds, then I would need about 425 8-core computers, all processing different parts of the input data, to complete the run in time.

Assuming you have the data, and the two map/reduce executables, and you have unlimited access to AWS or GCE, what is a solution to this problem that I can implement with the fewest lines of code and/or script (and not ignoring potential IO or other non-CPU bottlenecks)?

(As an aside, it would be interesting to also knowing what would execute with the fewest nodes, if different from the solution with fewest SLOC)

Comment: I'd recommend expanding a bit on what your data looks like and what you want to query for. Depending on those details, a solution like [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/what-is-bigquery) might make more sense.

Comment: For the purpose of this question, imagine the data is one huge table where every row describes what some particular automobile (model / make etc) did (number of miles, how much gas, etc) for some week out of the last 2 years, and the table describes 10 million autos. The map/reduce is NOT a "query"-- it is an analysis that results in an aggregated report with many tables and charts. I would love to use BigQuery if only the data processing could be expressed in SQL-- but it can't. The SQL equivalent, if it even exists, would require thousands of passes over the data rather than just one.